# How can I implement testable, maintainable real-time logic?

Tags: java, c++, logic, python-2.7

**assumption 1**: you have a suite of modules (very maintainable, with tests) for real-time monitoring.  They all run very quickly but are executed repeatedly.  They are all required to return a boolean flag, but may also return other data.  For example, the CheckParrot module would return if a parrot is observed to be dead, or not.  The SeekMorlocks module would return true if it found any, but additionally the number, heading, and distance.

**assumption 2**:  your applications will tie these modules together using some sort of custom algorithm, which might include state variables.  Examples include RTS games, trading programs, vehicle monitoring systems, etc.  The algorithm can be represented by a truth table, or equivalently, a [programmable logic array](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Comb/pla.html).

**question**: What open source is out there to help with implementing a programmable logic array, where the inputs and outputs are executable modules?  The goal is to isolate the algorithm (PLA) for independent testing, and easily plug modules into it.

At the moment I am mostly interested in a Java solution but am also curious about any C++ or Python.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [Drools](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-expert.html)

It's rules engine and a set of tools to create / test them.

Comment: Nice project. Since it's not totally obvious from the link, it's for Java1.5+.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are no libraries for *exact* real-time monitoring.  This is based on the facts that monitoring requires overhead and due to the overhead, it will not be real-time.

In the Embedded Systems arena, we usually find some test point pin (e.g. GPIO), that we can output a pulse to.  We then hook up either an oscilloscope or a logic analyzer to the pin to capture real-time trace data.  We either use the tool's data analysis functions or have the tool download the data to another application that can process the data, such as LabView or MatLab.  This has minimal effect to the real-time nature of the application.

You may be able to find an In-Circuit Emulator for your processor that is faster than your processor and can provide profiling and other real-time data gathering.

Remember, data output takes time and so your application may no longer be "real-time".  You could write the data to a memory location, then have the application dump the data before it exits.  I've done this with JTAG debuggers.

Although you could find some analysis tools, characterize their performance, and factor that into your "real-time" needs.